# Pass an instace of a class to another file in php

Tags: php

I'm quite new to PHP OO programming. I have a basic understanding of OOP. I'm transitioning from procedural to OOP and I'm having some problems with passing an instace of a class to another file in php.

I have read somewhere that if you would like to pass an instance of a class to another php file you would need:

`testA.php`:

```
$user = new User($login);
```

`testB.php`:

```
require_once('testA.php');
echo $user->getLogin();
```

That is cool and it worked perfectly for a simples example. It displayed the login as intended. Now lets go to a more complex example.

I have a form where the user inputs his `login` and `password`. This form is sent to `login-exec.php`. After making the verifications the method `loginIntoWebsite()` from the class `User`will redirect the user to `member-profile.php`. My problem begins right here. In my `member-profile.php` I made the necessary include of `login-exec.php`.

A simple logical diagram: `form -> login-exec.php -> User::loginIntoWebsite() -> member-profile.php`.

`logic-exec.php`:

```
...
$user = new User($login, $password);
    if($user->loginIntoWebsite()){
        header("location: member-profile.php");
    }else{
        header("location: login-failed.php");
    }
    exit();
```

`User::loginIntoWebsite()`:

```
//validations and mysql queries above 
if(password_verify($password, $passwordHashDB)){
     //Login Successful
     $this->attributeValuesToAttributes($memberID, $firstName, $lastName, $profilePicture, $moneyAmount);
     $_SESSION['LOGIN_USER'] = $login;
     $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $memberID;
     $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $firstName;
     $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $lastName;
     $_SESSION['SESSION_ID'] = session_regenerate_id();
     session_write_close();
     return true;
}else{
     return false;
}
```

`member-profile.php`:

```
include('login-exec.php');
if(isset($user)){
    echo "user is set in member-profile.php";
    echo $user->getLogin();
}else{
    echo "uset is not set in member-profile.php";
}
```

As you guessed it's echoed `user is not set in member-profile.php". Does it have anything to do with the`header("location: member-profile.php");`?

Comment: Have you tried without calling `exit();` in the login-exec file?

Comment: @JeremyHarris I have. Still the same result. EDIT: I should metion that the class User is a child of Identifier. Does that have any problem?

Comment: This check is wrong `if(isset($user))` you can't use the same object between two requests (since there is redirect). It is stateless. Maybe you should check if user is logged or not using something like `if(isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_USER'])){` ?

Comment: @DanMiller I agree with you till a certain point. If we can't use an instace of a class to another file in php what is the point of oop? If I could pass User to another page I could save a lot of queries. Lets say I do what you suggested. I would have to query the DB to get all the data that was already stored in queries before.

Comment: I think you confuse `require`/`include` with redirecting. This is not the same thing

Comment: @DanMiller I understand the concept of the two and the differences. What I meant by `If I could pass User to another page I could save a lot of queries` was `If I could pass an instance of User to another page I could save a lot of queries`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer-Opinion**

This part:

```
testA.php:

$user = new User($login);
testB.php:

require_once('testA.php');
echo $user->getLogin();
```

> That is cool and it worked perfectly

Yes. It works, but it's **not cool**.

I'm looking your code further... Actually,you're trying to make stuff with OOP without undestanding how it should works "right". You are using `classes` & `objects` , but still your mind thinks in "`procedural style`". You will have more & more problems further. It's not "right" OOP-way for this stuff (e.g. now I see - you want implement thing like `"Autorization"` & `including files` like it is `"routing"`).

**Advice**: start read about basic patters(Singelton,etc.),then MVC in common words, choose simplest MVC-framevork, etc. Summary: **for the moment you are not on right way**.

Comment: Can you point me in a good direction? Links? I have learned from my teachers and others that what I learned through the years was not the right way. I'm looking into google but I'm afraid that I'll end up reading the same crappy material that I read many years ago.

Comment: Ok. You know about Classes & Objects. You're doing now stuff in "MVC manner", but thinking in "procedural manner" (sorry, I don`t know how to say properly). For starting: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mvc-for-noobs--net-10488, https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns--net-12752, then look/search about "MVC frameworks".